# class-validator doesn't appear to do anything in NestJS application

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm setting up a new NestJS application, and I've just added class-validator in order to validate controller input, but it seems to be completely ignored. This is the DTO:

```
import {IsString} from 'class-validator';

export class CreateCompanyDto {
    @IsString()
    name: string | undefined;
}
```

This is the controller:

```
import {
    Body,
    Controller,
    InternalServerErrorException,
    Post,
    Request,
    UseGuards, ValidationPipe
} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {User} from 'firebase';
import {AuthGuard} from '../auth/auth.guard';
import {CurrentUser} from '../auth/current-user.decorator';
import {CreateCompanyDto} from './dto/create-company.dto';

@Controller('vendor')
export class VendorController {

    @Post()
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    async create(@CurrentUser() user: User, @Request() req: any, @Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) company: CreateCompanyDto) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(company));
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('meh?');

         // irrelevant code
    }

}
```

I would expect the code to throw a validation error and never hit the method itself, but instead it runs into the exception, and the object is logged exactly as it came in.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
        "prebuild": "(cd src && rm settings.json && ln -s ../configs/prod.json settings.json)",
        "build": "tsc",
        "prebuild:dev": "(cd src && rm settings.json && ln -s ../configs/dev.json settings.json)",
        "build:dev": "tsc",
        "serve": "concurrently \"npm run build:dev -- --watch\" \"firebase emulators:start --only functions\"",
        "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "8"
    },
    "main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.6.0",
        "@nestjs/common": "^6.11.11",
        "@nestjs/core": "^6.11.11",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.11.11",
        "@types/airtable": "^0.5.7",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
        "airtable": "^0.8.1",
        "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
        "class-validator": "^0.11.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^7.10.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "slugify": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
        "tslint": "^6.0.0",
        "typescript": "~3.7.5"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

What am I missing here?

**Update**
I did a little debugging, and I can tell where it's going wrong, even though I still don't know why.

In the ValidationPipe.transform method, it returns the raw input, because metatype is undefined:

```
    async transform(value, metadata) {
        const { metatype } = metadata;
        if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metadata)) {
            return value;
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issues where all my code was fine, just a silly mistake I had done was, I had put the line ```app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());``` after app.listen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the debugging gave me enough info to find the issue on Google, where I found this Github issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/690

You need to enable `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file for this to work.

Answer (score 39):

in `main.ts` add `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());`:

```js
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.enableCors();
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: For me it still doesn't work and I added 
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
@Controller()
export class MyFooController {

}

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are using a guard in your route. The guard would run before the class-validator. This means that you would need to implement the class-validator inside the canActivate function of your guard.

Related to: [How to validate dto with class-validator before passing to passportjs AuthGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73953048/how-to-validate-dto-with-class-validator-before-passing-to-passportjs-authguard)

Comment: this was the case for me too, thanks for sharing a link to a related question

Answer (score 0):

In my case the validations did not work as I did not have the class-transformer dependency in my application. Hope this helps someone.
You need both class-validator and class-transformer

> $ npm i --save class-validator class-transformer

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install class-transformer --save
```

Installing this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step on fresh installed nestJS,

1. Installed class validator package by running command "**npm i class-validator**"
2. No change required in tsconfig.json file, as default value is true for "**emitDecoratorMetadata**" key