# Change dto field value in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm new in nest js. I want to do a transformation for incoming request:

```
import { IsPhoneNumber } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class PhoneLoginDto {
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.replace(/^0/, '+98'))
  @IsPhoneNumber()
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

But this is not working, should it be done here in dto?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class-validator doesn't appear to do anything in NestJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616889/class-validator-doesnt-appear-to-do-anything-in-nestjs-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to pass transform:true in main.ts:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also setting with this:

```js
// on app.module.ts

// ...
providers: [
// ...
        {
            provide: APP_PIPE,
            useFactory: () => new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })
        }
]
```